# PHP script for orders not entering orders into MySql DB (XAMPP in use)

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am doing a project for my faculty, some kind of web app for ordering, i.e. UPS to pick up the mail you want to send. And I have problem that when I run the order form with submit, the script I created is not inserting the data into the table in my DB (connection is working, I tested it).

```
    if(isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_POST['contact']) && isset($_POST['adress']) && isset($_POST['priority']) && isset($_POST['box_size'])){
    if(isset($_POST['del_name']) && isset($_POST['del_lname']) && isset($_POST['del_adress']) && isset($_POST['del_pob'])){
        if($_POST['priority'] == "Ne" && $_POST['box_size'] == "1*1*1"){
            $_POST['price'] = "50kn";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO orders SET price='$_POST[price]', city='$_POST[city]', contact='$_POST[contact],
                    adress='$_POST[adress]', del_adress='$_POST[del_adress]', del_pob='$_POST[del_pob]', box_size='$_POST[box_size]',
                    priority='$_POST[priority]', del_name='$_POST[del_name]', del_lname='$_POST[lname]'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
        }
```

The code above illustrates my conditions, checking if all fields in form are set. All attributes in table are `varchar`.

```
<form name="form2" method="post" action="order_script.php">
    <h2>Pošiljatelj</h2>
        <p><!--Ovdje ide ime $_GET od ulogiranog--></p>
        <p><!--Ovdje ide $_GET prezime od ulogiranog--></p>
        <p>Grad/Mjesto: <input type="text" name="city" size="25" maxlength="20" value=""/></p>
        <p>Kontakt broj: <input type="text" name="contact" size="25" maxlength="20" value=""/></p>
        <p>Adresa: <input type="text" name="adress" size="25" maxlength="20" value=""/></p>
        <!--select for box_size-->
        <p>Brzina dostave/Prioritet: <select name="priority">
        <option value="">Da</option>
        <option value="">Ne</option>
        </select></p>

    <p>Veličina kutije: <select name="box_size">
        <option value="sm">1*1*1</option>
        <option value="md">2*2*2</option>
        <option value="lg">3*3*3</option>
        <option value="xl">4*4*4</option>
        </select></p>

    <h2>Primatelj</h2>
        <p>Ime: <input type="text" name="del_name" size="25" maxlength="20" value=""/></p>
        <p>Prezime: <input type="text" name="del_lname" size="25" maxlength="20" value=""/></p>
        <p>Adresa: <input type="text" name="del_adress" size="25" maxlength="20" value=""/></p>
        <p>Poštanski broj: <input type="text" name="del_pob" size="25" maxlength="20" value=""/></p>

        <!--Price of delivery hidden -->

        <input type="hidden" name="price" size="25" maxlength="20" value=""/></p>

        <p><input type="submit" name="order" value="Naruči"/></p><br></br>
</form>
```

So when I submit the form it just runs the script and shows empty page.

Comment: Do you mean your sql query not executed? cost me 5 mins to understanding `orders` words on your question title lol

Comment: If your code is exact copy, you have a syntax error in your query: you forgot to terminate string at `contact='$_POST[contact],`

Comment: Look at your error logs? Is that your complete PHP code, if so missing some `}`s. Also SQL injections and `isset` can take multiple variables.

Comment: I think it doesn't executes sql query because it runs the script but it does nothing , it passes first two conditions because I have 2 else's to execute if it doesn't. So I think it doesn't run sql orders. Srry I am stupid :(

Comment: corrected ' on contact still not working :S

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems with the code provided. First, there's an apostrophe missing (as indicated by lolbas), and two closing brackets missing. Here's a block with no syntax errors:

```
if(isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_POST['contact']) && isset($_POST['adress']) && isset($_POST['priority']) && isset($_POST['box_size'])){
    if(isset($_POST['del_name']) && isset($_POST['del_lname']) && isset($_POST['del_adress']) && isset($_POST['del_pob'])){
        if($_POST['priority'] == "Ne" && $_POST['box_size'] == "1*1*1"){
            $_POST['price'] = "50kn";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO orders SET price='$_POST[price]', city='$_POST[city]', contact='$_POST[contact]',
                    adress='$_POST[adress]', del_adress='$_POST[del_adress]', del_pob='$_POST[del_pob]', 
                    box_size='$_POST[box_size]', priority='$_POST[priority]', del_name='$_POST[del_name]', del_lname='$_POST[lname]'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you're checking if $_POST['priority'] == "Ne", but your SELECT options don't have any values set:

```
<select name="priority">
    <option value="">Da</option>
    <option value="">Ne</option>
</select>
```

... so your test is always false, and the query is not executed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query :

```
INSERT INTO orders (city, contact, adress, priority, box_size, del_name, del_lname, del_adress, del_pob)
VALUES ('$_POST[price]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[contact], '$_POST[adress]', '$_POST[del_adress]','$_POST[del_pob]', '$_POST[box_size]', '$_POST[priority]', '$_POST[del_name]', '$_POST[lname]');
```

Comment: The syntax of `INSERT` statement used by OP is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check all this steps. Maybe this will help you a lot:

1. `mysql_query` was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, so check your PHP version.
2. Try to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of [MySQL Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php).
3. Your third `if` is incorrect it will not work. Use `var_dump` to check if `$_POST['priority'] == "Ne"` and `$_POST['box_size'] == "1*1*1"` are return correct values. If it's not, correct it.
4. Your query also incorrect try this

```sql
INSERT INTO orders(city, contact, adress, priority, box_size, del_name, del_lname, del_adress, del_pob) VALUES ('$_POST[price]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[contact], '$_POST[adress]', '$_POST[del_adress]','$_POST[del_pob]', '$_POST[box_size]', '$_POST[priority]', '$_POST[del_name]', '$_POST[lname]');
```

Good lack.